# How to get email address against email id in Job data view?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data-views

Job data view provides the status of an email if it was delivered or not but it provides only Job Id and Email Id. This email id is a numeric number and not the email address.

How to get Email address against this email id provided in Job data view.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [documentation of salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) regarding the dataviews.

The Job data_view does not give information about the status of an email. It just tells you that the a job has been scheduled for an email send process (could also be canceled). The email id is a unique id for the email in html form like it was stored inside the marketing cloud. It is not correlated to an email address and will never be correlated to that. If you want to know if an email was delivered or not you are looking for the _Bounce Dataview and not the _Job Dataview. When you want to know the emails which have been sent to by a particular job you are looking for a join from 2/3 tables depending on your use case (_Job with _Sent and _Subscribers).

If you need the Job information you need to query _Job
if you need the _Sent information you need to query _Sent
If you want to know who has bounce you need _Bounce (even tells which domain)
If you want to know the email address from the subscribers you have sent to you are looking for a join between _Sent and _Subscribers.

Comment: 1. Job data view has one field called "DeliveredTime" (description - The time the email was delivered). What does this field mean? 
2. Tracking of a bounced email can take up to 3 days to get updated back in marketing cloud. If I want to get status of an email on very next day, how do I get a list of all emails which were delivered yesterday?
It might be possible that an email address is bounce but tracking data for the same was received after 3 days instead of very next day.

Comment: 1. This field can also be empty. For me delivered time is empty very often because sometimes you cannot say the time when the email was delivered (like journey builder sends or sends with hourly thresholds etc). 2. You will not ever get a correct information on the second day when it comes to bounces which may take up to 3 days. Thats the way it is. You can see which emails have been opened or send or clicked but you won't see a metric that shows you "delivered". The best it gets is to query the _send dataview and ignore those that bounced on the second day. Thats closest to your "delivered"

Answer (score 1):

I had a word with salesforce marketing cloud support team.

To get email ids against job data views, one has to put a join between job data view, send data view and subscribers data view. Putting a join between these three tables will give email address against email id (numeric number) and job id.

Though it won't be possible to get email delivery status against each email using this method. Delivery datetime provided in job data view is for that particular job and not for the specific email address.

Bottom line is, marketing cloud doesn't provide a separate table which provides email delivered datetime. As of now this can be only accessible at aggregate level through standard reports available in marketing cloud.

Answer (score -1):

Joining Data views _Job, _Sent and _Subscribers can be a solution, however this might be tricky as _Subscribers Data view contains email address of the first email that was sent to the MC contact. If subscriber email changes (for instance you are sendig via journey builder on a DE entry source which has a different email for a particular subscriber than it is saved in All subscribers list) and you do not change new email address in All Subscribers list, you will get an old email address from _Subscribers data view.